# Program using only specific memory

Tags: linux, gcc, memory

I would like my program running on 32 bit linux to use only memory below 0x0804800.

I managed to move stack to lower address using set/get/makecontext functions, but how to move the rest of the executable?

I tried using gcc -Ttext=addr, where addr is below 0x08048000, but I keep getting segmentation faults when trying to run generated executable. Why?

Simple PoC giving me the same result:

poc.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("abc\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with: `gcc -m32 -o poc -Ttext=0x8000000`

gcc version 4.8.4

Comment: You can shuffle around the place where your executable is loaded by supplying a custom linker script to the linker. The linker script tells the linker where to load the binary. However, this may not work with dynamically linked binaries. A further complication arises in that Linux refuses to map pages to the lowest megabyte in the address space (this limit can be configured with a sysconf).

Comment: @FUZxxl shouldn't -Ttext take care of that? And why would it cause segmentation faults anyway?

Comment: Where does it segfault?  What does your debugger say?

Comment: *"I keep getting segmentation faults"*: are you sure it's because of the memory location ?  Isn't it caused by misbehavior in your code ?

Comment: @Josh That doesn't change the linker script as far as I know. Also, you have to change `malloc()` and `mmap()` to never allocate memory above that address, too.

Comment: @NateEldredge
@Christophe

I put a breakpoint in gdb on beggining of `main` and SIGSEGV happens before it is reached. Also, changing the `addr` in `-Ttext=addr` to something over 0x8048000 makes the sigsegv disappear.

Gdb states:
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xf7fddb33 in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2

Comment: @FUZxxl of course, `mmap` and `malloc` are handled in code, but for now I have to deal with the problem at hand ;)

Comment: @Josh Can you provide us with a reproducible test case so we can find out what the problem is? Debugging a segfault without the crashing binary at hand is difficult.

Comment: @FUZxxl I eddited my post to provide code.

Comment: [This](https://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2000-07/msg00102.html) might be related.